# Eclipse.ini file not present in windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse

In my eclipse am getting this error An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace". Java heap space
  [image]

For that i surfed online. they told to edit the eclipse.ini file. The eclipse.ini file is located in the eclipse home directory. When i searched into my eclipse home directory. eclipse.ini file is not present.
[image]

Comment: Just redownload eclipse if you don't have the .ini file

Comment: maybe file is hidden or deleted, I can confirm that I have used last 3 version on win 7 and all of them had eclipse.ini file

Comment: According to Eclipseepedia ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini ) the file should be there or in $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini. AFAIR for me every eclipse downloaded by me had one.